# Drupal - How to create internal and external links with module

Tags: php, drupal-7

In drupal 4.x, in contents, links are created like this
[url=1]Some text[/url]
So when "Some text" click it open node 1.

Sometime it may link to external url also. like below:
[url=http://www.abc.com/somepage.html] external link [/url]

same thing how can i do it in drupal 7.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Drupal [bbcode.module](https://drupal.org/project/bbcode) adds a BBCode filter to Drupal. This allows you to use HTML-like tags as an alternative to HTML itself for adding markup to your posts. [BBCode](https://drupal.org/project/bbcode) is easier to use than HTML and helps to prevent malicious users from disrupting your site's formatting.

It uses markup based upon [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode).